# Edit String field value when serializing object with Jackson

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson, xss

In Spring MVC project, I have controllers which return data in the form of various objects. Later these objects are serialized to JSON, and JSON returned as a response to a client.

This is achieved by registering custom `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter` with `configureMessageConverters()` in application config. The converter uses

`jackson.databind.ObjectWriter.writeValue(jackson.core.JsonGenerator, object)`

for object serialization.

Now I need to implement XSS protection. Since all data goes through the step of serialization, I want to filter here String values, removing all symbols except those in whitelist (alphanumeric and some punctuation signs).

Is there a way to provide Jackson with a filter which will edit String values during serialization?

Comment: I'm not quite sure I understood your problem but why don't you let the controlers do the checks ?

Comment: @Asoub I want to do it in one place.

Comment: Take a look at CharacterEscapes class https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-core/javadoc/2.5/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/io/CharacterEscapes.html

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: @shmosel I've posted my solution as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

I have an instance of `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter`. There, in method `writeInternal(Object object, HttpOutputMessage outputMessage)`, I create an instance of my custom mapper: `mapper = new KJsonMapper();` This mapper is then used there to generate JSON.

KJsonMapper.java:

```
public class KJsonMapper extends ObjectMapper {

    public KJsonMapper() {
        enableAntiXSS();
    }

    private void enableAntiXSS() {
        SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule("Anti-XSS Serializer",
            new Version(1, 0, 0, "FINAL", "klab", "klab.anti-xss-serializer"));
        module.addSerializer(String.class, new KJsonAntiXssSerializer());
        registerModule(module);
    }
}
```

The mapper itself uses custom JsonSerializer, which is to provide anti-xss filtering.

KJsonAntiXssSerializer.java:

```
public class KJsonAntiXssSerializer extends JsonSerializer<String> {

    public void serialize(String value, JsonGenerator jsonGenerator, SerializerProvider serializerProvider)
            throws IOException {
        if (value == null) {
            return;
        }
        String encodedValue = antiXss(value);
        jsonGenerator.writeString(encodedValue);
    }

    private String antiXss(String value) {
        // return processed value from here
    }
}
```